# Do I still need to assign one person to guard when I have a reinforced door?

Tags: this-war-of-mine

I could finally spare the resources to build a reinforced door. Since it has an alarm system, do I still need to assign someone to guard duty at night?

It would be nice to have an extra person sleep during the night, so they're not tired during the day and can work instead of sleep. Spares a bed, too.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I don't use an extra person because sleep is so important, and so far the alarm has worked just fine. So no you don't have to assign anyone unless you feel like it, but it's unnecessary.